# How to prove that the composite function is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $f:M \to N$ and $g:N \to K$ be smooth functions, where $M,N$ and $K$ are smooth manifolds. How to prove that the composite function $g \circ f$ is smooth, noting that the Chain Rule only applies to functions between Euclidean spaces ?

Should I write $g \circ f$ as $$g \circ f = Z^{-1} \circ Z \circ g \circ Y^{-1} \circ Y \circ f \circ X^{-1} \circ X$$  Where $X,Y,Z$ are charts in the atlases of $M,N,K$ respectively, Now since $g$ is smooth $h := Z \circ g \circ Y^{-1}$ is smooth by definition, and similarly since $f$ is smooth, $l := Y \circ f \circ X^{-1}$ is smooth, therefore $$g \circ f = Z^{-1} \circ h \circ l \circ X$$ where all those four functions are between Euclidean spaces, can I use chain rule here. I know it is a very basic question, I wanted to make sure my approach is standard or not

Thank you in advance,

Comment: The chain rule only applies to $\mathbb R^n$ and smoothness of functions between smooth manifolds is also defined via $\mathbb R^n$ (using charts), so no problem